# Jetty wants Jersey, but I'm not using it

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty

Building a relatively simple jetty app, following the instructions here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/maven-and-jetty.html

I'm not using Jersey, but mvn jetty:run complains about

```
Provider com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer not found
```

My pom.xml does not include any reference to Jersey. In fact, it is quite simple:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jettyVersion}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

What is making jetty look for Jersey?

Comment: What does `mvn dependency:tree` tell you?

Comment: mvn dependency:tree output: http://pastebin.com/kwMbBzH2

Comment: You know you can edit your question and add that paste content into it, right?  As for your issue, there's a dependency arriving from somewhere that has the jersey dependency in it.  Either in the project dependencies, or the project's setup of jetty-maven-plugin dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much machination, and gnashing of teeth, I think I stumbled about the answer. Whilst learning about maven, I was playing with shaded uber-jars. I had compiled one of the packages as an uper-jar, and installed it. When maven put it all together, it added a bit too much and broke my dependencies. Removing the shaded jar for local installation and just using it for distribution worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Search all of your dependencies for `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` files.

The one that has the entry for `com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer` is the one causing you problems.

Look at your project dependencies (aka `<project><dependencies>`) *and* your project's configuration of `jetty-maven-plugin` to see if that `<plugin>` has any extra dependencies added to it (aka `<plugin><dependencies>`).

Comment: Thanks for you help, Joakim! After following your suggestions, I stumbled across an surprising find: cloning my repo and running mvn jetty:run as another user works just fine. Where/how is jetty configured on a per-user basis?